# Can i stop a blackwidow macro while its being executed?

Tags: keyboard, macros, razer-keyboard

I'm trying to make a macro for my blackwidow keyboard, which has to be executed until i press a different button. Can anyone tell me how to do this, or how tp stop a macro from being executed halfway?

Comment: As far as I can tell, thats not possible. Just in case it is, and I missed something, it might help if you could mention the model, and more importantly the version of synapse you are using. V1 and V2 are VERY different.

Comment: Im using the Razer BlackWidow Ultimate. Im not using synapse, im using the Razer blackwidow configurator, which is a program that comes with it. Is it better 2 use synapse?

Comment: both have advantages and disadvantages. My keyboard gets switched between systems so I prefer syapse. the old configurator works fine as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could try *Razer Synapse 2.0* select `Keyboard > Customize` then click on key with macro assigned and in popup window `Key Assigment` set `Playback Option` as *Toggle continuous playback on/off using assigned key*.

It will stop/interrupt your macro by pressing the same key by which it was started.

P.S. Should say about one drawback of the described above method: the macro script will be running forever until you stop it.

Comment: In my experience, the macro is not interrupted. What happens is that the macro stops looping, but if the macro has delays, then it will still complete the "current" run.

Answer (score 0):

If you have set the macro option to run a set number of times (ie 50 times) and then wish to interrupt it, the only way I have found to stop the process midway is to unplug the keyboard's usb cable from the PC then reinsert. It's not very elegant, but it works when even a restart won't.